# Why doesn't this promise work in my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have a simple service wrapped around [hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js). I call it hello-service.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("MyApp.components.hello", []).

factory("HelloService", function()
{    
    return window.hello; //assume hello has been loaded
});
```

Then I have a controller called menu-controller which displays a login link:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("MyApp.components.menu", ["MyApp.components.hello"]).

controller("MenuController", ['$scope', 'HelloService', function($scope, HelloService)
{
    HelloService.on('auth.login', function(auth)
    {
        HelloService('facebook').api('/me').then(function(r)
        {
            $scope.loginLink = "Hi, " + r.name;
        });
    });
}]);
```

And here is my template:

```
<ul class="menu" ng-controller="MenuController">
    <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/upload">Upload</a></li>
    <li>{{loginLink}}</li>
</ul>
```

I know the code gets to the $scope.loginLink bit, and I can verify that r.name is correct using console.log. However {{loginLink}} in my template never gets updated and I can't work out why.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see your template file ?

Comment: Updated question with template. Also I changed the code a bit as it turns out my if condition could just be handled by hello.on

Comment: Have you tried using `$scope.$apply();` after updating `loginLink`? It's necessary sometimes when interacting with services.

Comment: Exactly, when you get data from outside sources that are not $resource or $http, it doesn't get applied to your scope immediately. Wrap it in a $scope.$apply and see if it works. This guy wrote a nice piece on it: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html